# Changing Ip to HostName

Tags: ip, localhost, virtual-machine, host

I always connect to my VM using the IP address. But am not able to connect using the hostname.

Now when I try to access webservices configured on that machine i cannot do so as it gives me a hostname not resolved error.

Is it possible to have the IP refer the hostname in any way?
Do some settings need to be changed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows change this file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and on Linux this file `/etc/hosts`.

Add:

```
IP  your.hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

First please mention your OS clearly..Under linux you need to edit */etc/hostname* and */etc/hosts*

Also further you need to change it under *Virtual Machine Name*

This Server Fault post might help - https://serverfault.com/questions/257485/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-vm-using-vmware